# PHP My Regex Can't Find First Hashtags

Tags: php, string

i try to get all hashtags in my string and work fine but first hashtags my code not find it:

```
$string = '#q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q #q';

$hashtag_url = $weburl. "hashtag/\\0";
$string = preg_replace("(\s#\w+)", "<a href='$hashtag_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

See Image(All Hashtag Is Ok, Only First Not):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5buk.png]

i need example if my link have  i dont want to find hashtag in link:

```
http://localhost/#gasd3 #qtest (get only #qtest)
```

Comment: Use this `, " ".$string);` because your REGEX matches only if a space is given, but the first hashtag has no space before it

Comment: The regex specifically requires a space character preceding `#`, which your first `#q` doesn't have.

Comment: "It works on my end"

Answer (score 1):

There is no space before the first hashtag...try this:

```
 preg_replace("/(\s*#\w+)/i", "<a href='$hashtag_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

The asterisk means that the space may be there zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make the \s optional like so..

```
$string = preg_replace("((\s)?#\w+)", "<a href='$hashtag_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

It's easier to understand when the (\s) is in brackets followed by the ? which is a modifier to tell the regex that the (\s) is optional.

You can do it like so without the brackets, which looks messier but is better for the regex engine.

```
$string = preg_replace("(\s?#\w+)", "<a href='$hashtag_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that regex101 is excellent if you want to play around with regex, your regex looks like this https://regex101.com/r/nA2hB2/1